# Combination to be produced with condition in R

Tags: r, combinations

Hi I have 4 strings to execute combinations- 1)PES 2)PEA 3)PAL 4)PSL

I have to write a script to perform combination (combinatorial - ncr formula) such that I only need combination with following algorithm

```
If I have PAL in the combination output then keep PAL only and remove other string (PEA,PES,PSL) for egs if I have one of combination as PAL PSL then I only need PAL in output which I think will be in data frame format.
```

If I have PEA and not PAL in my output then just keep PEA and not include other (PES and PSL) for example if I have combination like PEA PSL then I only need PEA in my output

All are strings

outcome - 1) PAL 2)PEA 3)PSL+PES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would return combinations of sizes 4 to 1 and remove the non-PAL items from any that have PAL in them. It uses the `combn` function which returns combination-sets of a particular size:

```
lapply( lapply(1:4 , combn, x=strings), # modify if smaller set of sizes needed
  function(cx){
  apply(cx, 2, function(col) if( any(col=="PAL") ) {"PAL"} else { paste( col ) } ) } )
```

It wasn't clear how you wanted these delivered, since returning them in a "dataframe" doesn't really make sense because they are of varying lengths.

```
[[1]]
[1] "PES" "PEA" "PAL" "PSL"

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "PES" "PEA"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "PAL"

[[2]][[3]]
[1] "PES" "PSL"

[[2]][[4]]
[1] "PAL"

[[2]][[5]]
[1] "PEA" "PSL"

[[2]][[6]]
[1] "PAL"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "PAL"

[[3]][[2]]
[1] "PES" "PEA" "PSL"

[[3]][[3]]
[1] "PAL"

[[3]][[4]]
[1] "PAL"


[[4]]
[1] "PAL"
```